# How to animate svg icon on hover and while it appears in the view port?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to animate the SVG icon when a mouse hovers over it or when it appears in the view port.

But after the icon animates when it appears, it doesn't animate while the mouse hover.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Following is the code snippet. In the javascript, I am using window.addEventListener to check if the button is visible or not. When it is visible, a class is added to the div which triggers the animation.

In CSS, there is a class .animateButton which animates individual components of the SVG icon. I am using the path to select these components.

:hover is used to trigger the same animation but it is currently not functioning.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  
    var buttonTop = button.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var buttonIsVisible = (buttonTop - window.innerHeight+25) < 0 && buttonTop > 0;
    //console.log(buttonIsVisible);
    if (buttonIsVisible) {
        if (!button.classList.contains("animateButton")) {
        //console.log(button.className);
            button.classList.add("animateButton");
        }
    } else {
        button.className = "";
    }
})
```

```css
#button{
width:150px;
background-color:green;
color:white;
padding:.5rem;
text-align: center;
margin-top:500px;
margin-bottom:500px;
}

#button:hover path:nth-child(1){
    stroke-dasharray: 25px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
    animation: animate-icon .8s ease forwards;
}
#button:hover path:nth-child(2){
    stroke-dasharray: 25px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
    animation: animate-icon  .8s ease forwards .3s;
}
#button:hover path:nth-child(3), #button:hover path:nth-child(4){
    stroke-dasharray: 7px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 7px;
    animation: animate-icon .5s ease forwards .5s;
}

.animateButton path:nth-child(1){
    stroke-dasharray: 25px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
    animation: animate-icon .8s ease forwards;
}
.animateButton path:nth-child(2){
    stroke-dasharray: 25px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
    animation: animate-icon  .8s ease forwards .3s;
}
.animateButton path:nth-child(3), .animateButton path:nth-child(4){
    stroke-dasharray: 7px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 7px;
    animation: animate-icon .5s ease forwards .5s;
}

@keyframes animate-icon{
    to{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
Scroll down to see animation!!
</div>

<div id="button">
 <svg id="circle" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 25 25" fill="none"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path
                                    d="M16.6666 21.875V19.7917C16.6666 18.6866 16.2276 17.6268 15.4462 16.8454C14.6648 16.064 13.605 15.625 12.5 15.625H5.20829C4.10322 15.625 3.04342 16.064 2.26201 16.8454C1.48061 17.6268 1.04163 18.6866 1.04163 19.7917V21.875"
                                    stroke="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <path
                                    d="M8.85417 11.4583C11.1554 11.4583 13.0208 9.59285 13.0208 7.29167C13.0208 4.99048 11.1554 3.125 8.85417 3.125C6.55298 3.125 4.6875 4.99048 4.6875 7.29167C4.6875 9.59285 6.55298 11.4583 8.85417 11.4583Z"
                                    stroke="url(#paint1_linear)" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <path d="M20.8334 8.33337V14.5834" stroke="url(#paint2_linear)" stroke-width="2"
                                    stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <path d="M23.9584 11.4584H17.7084" stroke="url(#paint3_linear)" stroke-width="2"
                                    stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <defs>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="2.18637" y1="15.625" x2="8.84787"
                                        y2="24.9627" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="5.29803" y1="3.125" x2="13.3121" y2="7.61847"
                                        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="20.9066" y1="8.33337" x2="22.1606"
                                        y2="8.44587" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="18.1663" y1="11.4584" x2="18.7611"
                                        y2="13.543" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                </defs>
                            </svg>
<span class="buttonText"> Hover Me! </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intersection Observer`

```js
const intersectRatio = .2;
var options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: intersectRatio
}

var handleIntersect = function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      console.log("visble")
      entry.target.classList.add('animateButton');
      observer.unobserve(entry.target)
    } else
      console.log("invisble")
  });
  console.log("Handle");
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
document.querySelectorAll('#button').forEach(function(r) {
  observer.observe(r);
})
```

```css
#button {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}

#button:hover path:nth-child(1) {
  stroke-dasharray: 25px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
  animation: animate-icon .8s ease forwards;
}

#button:hover path:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dasharray: 25px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
  animation: animate-icon .8s ease forwards .3s;
}

#button:hover path:nth-child(3),
#button:hover path:nth-child(4) {
  stroke-dasharray: 7px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 7px;
  animation: animate-icon .5s ease forwards .5s;
}

.animateButton path:nth-child(1) {
  stroke-dasharray: 25px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
  animation: animate-icon .8s ease forwards;
}

.animateButton path:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dasharray: 25px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
  animation: animate-icon .8s ease forwards .3s;
}

.animateButton path:nth-child(3),
.animateButton path:nth-child(4) {
  stroke-dasharray: 7px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 7px;
  animation: animate-icon .5s ease forwards .5s;
}

@keyframes animate-icon {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Scroll down to see animation!!
</div>

<div id="button">
  <svg id="circle" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 25 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path
                                    d="M16.6666 21.875V19.7917C16.6666 18.6866 16.2276 17.6268 15.4462 16.8454C14.6648 16.064 13.605 15.625 12.5 15.625H5.20829C4.10322 15.625 3.04342 16.064 2.26201 16.8454C1.48061 17.6268 1.04163 18.6866 1.04163 19.7917V21.875"
                                    stroke="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <path
                                    d="M8.85417 11.4583C11.1554 11.4583 13.0208 9.59285 13.0208 7.29167C13.0208 4.99048 11.1554 3.125 8.85417 3.125C6.55298 3.125 4.6875 4.99048 4.6875 7.29167C4.6875 9.59285 6.55298 11.4583 8.85417 11.4583Z"
                                    stroke="url(#paint1_linear)" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <path d="M20.8334 8.33337V14.5834" stroke="url(#paint2_linear)" stroke-width="2"
                                    stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <path d="M23.9584 11.4584H17.7084" stroke="url(#paint3_linear)" stroke-width="2"
                                    stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <defs>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="2.18637" y1="15.625" x2="8.84787"
                                        y2="24.9627" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="5.29803" y1="3.125" x2="13.3121" y2="7.61847"
                                        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="20.9066" y1="8.33337" x2="22.1606"
                                        y2="8.44587" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="18.1663" y1="11.4584" x2="18.7611"
                                        y2="13.543" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                </defs>
                            </svg>
  <span class="buttonText"> Hover Me! </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a css animation is not so easy to restart. css-tricks has an article about this: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/. The trick I used is to reinsert the element into the page. You could also try to use the `void element.offsetWidth;` solution.

Below is the reinsert solution mentioned in the article applied. I had to nest 2 events because when cloning the element the mouseenter event was retriggered automatically on mousemove.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('button');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  
    var buttonTop = btn.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var buttonIsVisible = (buttonTop - window.innerHeight+25) < 0 && buttonTop > 0;
    //console.log(buttonIsVisible);
    if (buttonIsVisible) {
        if (!btn.classList.contains("animateButton")) {
        //console.log(btn.className);
            btn.classList.add("animateButton");
        }
    } else {
        btn.className = "";
    }
})

let animateIt = () => {
    let newone = btn.cloneNode(true);
    btn.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, btn);
    btn = document.getElementById('button');

    // apply the event when leaving
    // the newly inserted element
    // to prevent constant animation retriggering
    btn.addEventListener('mouseout', () =>
        btn.addEventListener('mouseenter', animateIt)
    );
};

btn.addEventListener('mouseenter', animateIt);
```

```css
#button {
width:150px;
background-color:green;
color:white;
padding:.5rem;
text-align: center;
margin-top:500px;
margin-bottom:500px;
}

#button:hover path:nth-child(1){
    stroke-dasharray: 25px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
    animation: animate-icon .8s ease forwards;
}
#button:hover path:nth-child(2){
    stroke-dasharray: 25px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
    animation: animate-icon  .8s ease forwards .3s;
}
#button:hover path:nth-child(3), #button:hover path:nth-child(4){
    stroke-dasharray: 7px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 7px;
    animation: animate-icon .5s ease forwards .5s;
}

.animateButton path:nth-child(1){
    stroke-dasharray: 25px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
    animation: animate-icon .8s ease forwards;
}
.animateButton path:nth-child(2){
    stroke-dasharray: 25px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 25px;
    animation: animate-icon  .8s ease forwards .3s;
}
.animateButton path:nth-child(3), .animateButton path:nth-child(4){
    stroke-dasharray: 7px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 7px;
    animation: animate-icon .5s ease forwards .5s;
}

@keyframes animate-icon{
    to{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
Scroll down to see animation!!
</div>

<div id="button">
 <svg id="circle" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 25 25" fill="none"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path
                                    d="M16.6666 21.875V19.7917C16.6666 18.6866 16.2276 17.6268 15.4462 16.8454C14.6648 16.064 13.605 15.625 12.5 15.625H5.20829C4.10322 15.625 3.04342 16.064 2.26201 16.8454C1.48061 17.6268 1.04163 18.6866 1.04163 19.7917V21.875"
                                    stroke="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <path
                                    d="M8.85417 11.4583C11.1554 11.4583 13.0208 9.59285 13.0208 7.29167C13.0208 4.99048 11.1554 3.125 8.85417 3.125C6.55298 3.125 4.6875 4.99048 4.6875 7.29167C4.6875 9.59285 6.55298 11.4583 8.85417 11.4583Z"
                                    stroke="url(#paint1_linear)" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                                    stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <path d="M20.8334 8.33337V14.5834" stroke="url(#paint2_linear)" stroke-width="2"
                                    stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <path d="M23.9584 11.4584H17.7084" stroke="url(#paint3_linear)" stroke-width="2"
                                    stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                <defs>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="2.18637" y1="15.625" x2="8.84787"
                                        y2="24.9627" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="5.29803" y1="3.125" x2="13.3121" y2="7.61847"
                                        gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint2_linear" x1="20.9066" y1="8.33337" x2="22.1606"
                                        y2="8.44587" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                    <linearGradient id="paint3_linear" x1="18.1663" y1="11.4584" x2="18.7611"
                                        y2="13.543" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <stop stop-color="#242E31" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0C1314" />
                                    </linearGradient>
                                </defs>
                            </svg>
<span class="buttonText"> Hover Me! </span>
</div>
```